# How to use SIMILAR TO or Posix in Knex for Postgres?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

Postgres supports `SIMILAR TO` and `POSIX` regular expressions allowing writing more powerful regular expressions than the `LIKE` operator does. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/functions-matching.html

I am using Knex to run queries on a Postgres database.
I know how to use `LIKE` with knex but I could not find the support for `SIMILAR TO` or POSIX regular expressions.

How can I use `SIMILAR TO` with knex or even better the POSIX expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the support for `POSIX`. It seems the `SIMILAR TO` operator is not supported. However, that is okay as POSIX allows to write more powerful regex than `SIMILAR TO`.

```
 .where('column', '~', 'pattern');
```

`~`: case sensitive match

`~*`: case-insensitive match

!~ and !~* negation of the corresponding operator.

https://github.com/knex/knex/pull/562/files